# Prestoshop - Cant add a category name in other language?

Tags: php, prestashop

After enabling Tamil Language, I tried to add a new category in the Tamil Language, by entering in Name field, automatically friedly-url  field also filled. But while submitting got the error:

> The link_rewrite field is invalid.

Tried many combinations, Tamil in name, english in friendly-url and vice versa. same error. 
Please guide to setup category in Tamil language.

PrestaShop version: 1.7.2.0

Thanks.

Comment: Which slug are you defining? Have you tried with a simple one with latin characters?

Comment: finally revisited all the tries, single space after the english in the friendly-url is the culprit. Now, ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake, a **space** after the english word in the friendly-url space, inserted by the google input tools when selecting the english word. When typed without space, its accepting now. Thanks idnovate for your kindness.